# Recurring traits of the neurotypical mind

Tags: behavior, autism

Classically, medicine has pathologized the autism spectrum, and labelled everyone who isn't on the spectrum (and other similar conditions) as 'neurotypical'.

My question is - if we can group and categorize traits of those who are on the spectrum, has the same thing been done for neurotypical people? Have there been any studies or books that have attempted to define the common characteristics of individuals with no type of classical disorder?

I wasn't sure which tags would be appropriate here, so feel free to update.

Comment: "Neurotypical" is not a classical label, it's quite a recent label created by an autism advocate. You might look at the broader study of "personality", which covers a range of individual differences without necessarily labeling them in pathological terms (but not exclusively so).

Comment: neurotypicals have been classified and characterized on a wide variety of descriptors, including intelligence and personality continuums. The whole idea of "normal" comes from measurement theory. Perhaps see Gabor Mate on "The Myth of Normal"

Comment: This question seems way too broad to me.  Any psychometric measure, including clinical diagnostics themselves, personality inventories (as mentioned), cognitive abilities, etc, all cover the neurotypical range in their scopes.